# Nifi: calculate total rows count after paginating ExetuSQL/ExecuteSQLRecord

Tags: apache-nifi

With ExecuteSQL/ExecuteSQLRecord processors you can specify "Output Batch Size" which will result in multiple Flow Files. Each Flow File contains `executesql.row.count`.

*Now what is the simplest way to calculate a `sum(executesql.row.count)` for single table?*

It's possible to do `AttributesToJSON (drop content) => MergeContent (defragment) => QueryRecord (counting) => EvaluateJSONPath (back to attribute)`. Still it's too complex IMHO. Ideally, I would like to add attributes somehow, on/after `MergeContent`. The issue is that `MergeContent` is dropping attributes with the same key but different values. Also Nifi doesn't have any processor for adding dynamic number of attributes.

Comment: UpdateAttribute can add dynamic number of attributes

Comment: @BryanBende how does it solve my problem? The hardest part is how to merge/sum the results together

Comment: I'm not saying it solves your problem but you wrote "Nifi doesn't have any processor for adding dynamic number of attributes" so I was just responding to that saying that UpdateAttribute can add dynamic attributes

Comment: @BryanBende ow, sorry, that's a typo. It's actually about Nifi doesn't provide logic to aggregate the dynamic attributes

Answer (score 0):

I tried with the below, I was able to get sum(executesql.row.count)

[The NiFi Flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKKte.png)

First Update Attribute:
[Init Counter through Update Attribute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nHPb.png)

Second Update Attribute:
[Counter = Counter + executesql.row.count](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7DLs.png)

The ADVANCED tab of Second Update Attribute - to reset after it exceeds a threshold (if required):
[Reset Counter in Advanced option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQg60.png)